# onActivityResult is not called from class where startActivityForResult is called

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity, one NonActivity class and SearchActivity. NonActivity class calls startActivityForResult, but onActivityResult in nonActivity class is never called.

But I figured it out, that is called in MainActivity, when I implemented it for testing purposes. Could you please tell me if it is possible, that onActivityResult will be called from nonActivity class?

This is the code I am calling from NonActivity class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SearchActivity.class);
        //start SearchActivity through intent and expect for result. The result is based on result code, which is REQUEST_DISCOVERY 
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
    }
```

Thanks for your answer, if you need more code, I can put add.

Comment: Post another question and I will help. You cannot use the pass in activity as someone answered in your last post. For the question as is the answer by Egor is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` won't be called on a `NonActivity` class, because actually it wasn't the one that started the new `Activity`, your calling `startActivityForResult()` on your `MainActivity` object and `MainActivity` is where the `onActivityResult()` will be called. To call it back to the `NonActivity` just create a method inside the `NonActivity` and call it from the `MainActivity's` `onActivityResult()`, passing the arguments that you need.

Comment: OK, I thuought that is option to avoid this, because I wanted fully independent class that will take care for all the job. Thanks!

Comment: @anze87, You're welcome. By the way, you can try to decouple MainActivity from NonActivity by providing an interface, which NonActivity implements. This way your MainActivity will know NonActivity as a simple "listener" and will send it a callback from onActivityResult(). Seems like a better solution to me.

Comment: Could you give me a small example? I'm not sure if I understand exactly, I'm new at this thing.